# how to check a type in dynamic loop to avoid invalid function calls?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a loop which trims() all string values on accessed facility properties.  However, the facility object has an AdditionalInfo property which is a complex object as opposed to a string.  I need the function to only attempt to trim() string values and avoid calling trim() on non-string values.  I added a typeof check to my loop below.  Something is incorrect with this implementation though b/c I'm getting a compiler error.  Any idea how I can update the loop below to achieve what I'm describing?:

```
    fieldNames.forEach(x => {
        let propVal = '';
        let stringVal = '';
        if (facility && (x != fieldName)) {
            if ((typeof facility[x]) == "string") {
                facility[x] = (facility[x] || '').trim();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the compiler error?

Comment: Property trim() does not exist on type "string | AdditionalInfo"

Comment: `if (typeof facility[x] === 'string')`?  There should be no need to use `||` since it is a string in this case e.g `facility[x] = facility[x].trim()`

Comment: the code should works fine, can you please share with us **fieldName** and **facility** data that you use ?

Comment: What is the definition for `AdditionalInfo`? Edit you question and add more information about `AditionalInfo` and also what `fieldName` and `facility` is and how they are being used.

Answer (score -1):

you have to add **as string**, because the type of facility's item is string or AdditionalInfo

```js
fieldNames.forEach(x => {
        let propVal = '';
        let stringVal = '';
        if (facility && (x != fieldName)) {
            if ((typeof facility[x]) == "string") {
                facility[x] = (facility[x] as string).trim();
            }
        }
    });
```